# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\nota\nota.php on line 8

Tags: php, html, fatal-error

I can't fix this problem i had tried to see any error on html but it is all OK in html, the problem it is:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\nota\nota.php on line 8.

```
<?php 
    $ex1=$_REQUEST["txtEx1"];$ex2=$_REQUEST["txtEx2"];$ex3=$_REQUEST["txtEx3"];

    $PesoEx1=$_REQUEST=["txtPesoEx1"];$PesoEx2=$_REQUEST=["txtPesoEx2"];$PesoEx3=$_REQUEST=["txtPesoEx3"];

        $mediaPeso=$PesoEx1+$PesoEx2+$PesoEx3;

        /*this is the line 8*/$mediaNotas=(($ex1*$PesoEx1)+($ex2*$PesoEx2)+($ex3*$PesoEx3));

        $mediaFinal=$mediaNotas/$mediaPeso;
        echo "<br/>Media:".$mediaFinal;

?>
```

Comment: You cannot do arithmetic on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `$PesoEx1`, `$PesoEx2` and `$PesoEx3` variables. It should be like this:

```
$PesoEx1=$_REQUEST["txtPesoEx1"];
$PesoEx2=$_REQUEST["txtPesoEx2"];
$PesoEx3=$_REQUEST["txtPesoEx3"];
```

Comment: @GabrielCorreia please accept the answer to close the question.